# How do you query a nested object in mongodb to return a single json object?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

The data being used is:

```
     {  
       'name':'Arsenal FC',
       'squad':[  
          {  
             'id':'3174',
             'name':'Bernd Leno',
             'position':'Goalkeeper',
             'dateOfBirth':'1992-03-04',
             'nationality':'Germany',
             'role':'PLAYER'
          },
          {  
             'id':'7778',
             'name':'Petr Čech',
             'position':'Goalkeeper',
             'dateOfBirth':'1982-05-20',
             'nationality':'Czech Republic',
             'role':'PLAYER'
          },
          {  
             'id':'7780',
             'name':'Deyan Iliev',
             'position':'Goalkeeper',
             'dateOfBirth':'1995-02-25',
             'nationality':'FYR Macedonia',
             'role':'PLAYER'
          }
]
}
```

I am trying to return a single player object like below:

```
{  
             'id':'7778',
             'name':'Petr Čech',
             'position':'Goalkeeper',
             'dateOfBirth':'1982-05-20',
             'nationality':'Czech Republic',
             'role':'PLAYER'
          }
```

I am using mongodb, the query being used is `{"squad.id": id}` with id coming from the user input however, this returns the entire dataset. How do I get it to return a single player?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does allow querying nested object property in an array, but not project only a particular element of an array.

But instead if you wish to, you use can aggregate query rather than find, and use [$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) to find the index of element in array based on expression, and then further project only that item using [$arrayElementAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/)